# Opencart 2.x Event name in called function

Tags: opencart2.x, opencart-module

So I have 3 events who call the same function.

Would it be possible to obtain the event name directly in the function?

```
    $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('postorderchange', 'post.order.edit', 'module/postorderchange/on_order_change');
    $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('postorderchange', 'post.order.add', 'module/postorderchange/on_order_change');
    $this->model_extension_event->addEvent('postorderchange', 'post.order.history.add', 'module/postorderchange/on_order_change');
```

I want to be able to get the name of the event in the on_order_change() function.

Comment: you want to trigger different event with same name and same method name ?

Comment: I wanna know post.order.history.add inside the function

Answer (score 0):

`post.order.history.add` event trigger the `total/voucher/send` action.

you can check `send` function in following file.

`catalog/controller/total/voucher.php`

Inside the function : -

```
public function send($order_id) {
        $this->load->model('checkout/order');

        $order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($order_id);

        // If order status in the complete range create any vouchers that where in the order need to be made available.
        if (in_array($order_info['order_status_id'], $this->config->get('config_complete_status'))) {
            $voucher_query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, vtd.name AS theme FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "voucher` v LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "voucher_theme vt ON (v.voucher_theme_id = vt.voucher_theme_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "voucher_theme_description vtd ON (vt.voucher_theme_id = vtd.voucher_theme_id) WHERE v.order_id = '" . (int)$order_info['order_id'] . "' AND vtd.language_id = '" . (int)$order_info['language_id'] . "'");

            if ($voucher_query->num_rows) {
                // Send out any gift voucher mails
                $language = new Language($order_info['language_directory']);
                $language->load($order_info['language_directory']);
                $language->load('mail/voucher');

                foreach ($voucher_query->rows as $voucher) {
                    // HTML Mail
                    $data = array();

                    $data['title'] = sprintf($language->get('text_subject'), $voucher['from_name']);

                    $data['text_greeting'] = sprintf($language->get('text_greeting'), $this->currency->format($voucher['amount'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']));
                    $data['text_from'] = sprintf($language->get('text_from'), $voucher['from_name']);
                    $data['text_message'] = $language->get('text_message');
                    $data['text_redeem'] = sprintf($language->get('text_redeem'), $voucher['code']);
                    $data['text_footer'] = $language->get('text_footer');

                    if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $voucher['image'])) {
                        $data['image'] = $this->config->get('config_url') . 'image/' . $voucher['image'];
                    } else {
                        $data['image'] = '';
                    }

                    $data['store_name'] = $order_info['store_name'];
                    $data['store_url'] = $order_info['store_url'];
                    $data['message'] = nl2br($voucher['message']);

                    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/mail/voucher.tpl')) {
                        $html = $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/mail/voucher.tpl', $data);
                    } else {
                        $html = $this->load->view('default/template/mail/voucher.tpl', $data);
                    }

                    $mail = new Mail();
                    $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                    $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                    $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
                    $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
                    $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                    $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
                    $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');

                    $mail->setTo($voucher['to_email']);
                    $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                    $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($language->get('text_subject'), $voucher['from_name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                    $mail->setHtml($html);
                    $mail->send();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can modified here..